# My code don't refresh parent page in some cases

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using a thick box and want to refresh parent page when thicbox is closing. I use below code but it works sometime and dont work in some situations... waht is the problem with it?

```
<script>
    function close2()
    {
       parent.tb_remove();
       parent.location.reload(1)
    }
</script>

<input type="submit" name="save_new_task" id="save_new_task" onclick="close2()" style="width: 100px;text-align: center;" 
  class="button button-primary button-medium" value="<?Php _e("register","creat_mysite");?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because your submitting the form before the JavaScript get executed? If you want to submit your form and then perform a Javascript function you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#save_new_task').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        //Serialize your form
        //POST request


        //Maybe also try window.opener instead of parent
        //window.opener refers to the window that called window.open( ... ) to open the window from which it's called
        //window.parent refers to the parent of a window in a <(i)frame>
        window.opener.tb_remove();     
        window.opener.location.reload(); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know the context but from what i could figure out try the below
Try this:

```
   <script>
        function close2()
        {
           parent.tb_remove();
           parent.location.reload(1);
return true;
        }
    </script>
    <form onsubmit="return close2()" >
    <input type="submit" name="save_new_task" id="save_new_task" style="width: 100px;text-align: center;"  class="button button-primary button-medium" value="<?Php _e("register","creat_mysite");?>"/>
</form>
```